Ubuntu won't boot after reboot - end Kernel panic - not syncing
Before rebooting, I switched the display drivers on my ubuntu 20.04 machine from intel to nvidia using prime-select, then I ran sudo reboot. The machine never booted again with the error shown here.
I don't quite know what the issue is. I've tried to check the health of the disk by running sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda
with the output being:
Error 245 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15525 hours (646 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 60 28 3f 77 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00773f28 = 7814952

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 60 28 3f 77 40 00      00:05:13.862  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:05:13.861  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      00:05:13.861  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:05:13.860  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:05:13.860  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 244 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15525 hours (646 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 b8 28 3f 77 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00773f28 = 7814952

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 b8 28 3f 77 40 00      00:05:13.438  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:05:13.437  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      00:05:13.437  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:05:13.436  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:05:13.436  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 243 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15525 hours (646 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 00 30 3f 77 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00773f30 = 7814960

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 00 30 3f 77 40 00      00:05:13.006  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:05:13.005  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      00:05:13.005  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:05:13.004  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:05:13.004  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 242 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15525 hours (646 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 28 30 3f 77 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00773f30 = 7814960

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 28 30 3f 77 40 00      00:05:12.570  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:05:12.569  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      00:05:12.569  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:05:12.568  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:05:12.568  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

Error 241 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 15525 hours (646 days + 21 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 41 58 30 3f 77 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00773f30 = 7814960

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 58 30 3f 77 40 00      00:05:12.138  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 a0 00      00:05:12.138  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  27 00 00 00 00 00 e0 00      00:05:12.137  READ NATIVE MAX ADDRESS EXT [OBS-ACS-3]
  ec 00 00 00 00 00 a0 00      00:05:12.137  IDENTIFY DEVICE
  ef 03 45 00 00 00 a0 00      00:05:12.136  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing


Obviously something is wrong, it is showing errors but I cannot interpret the output from this command.
Any help is welcomed.
